# Why do the answers of calculating integrals not converge (my step by step solution and online calculator)?

Tags: integration

My solution:
$\displaystyle \int\frac{x^3+1}{x^2-3x+2} dx= \int (x+3+-\frac{2}{x-1}+\frac{9}{x-2})dx=\int xdx+\int 3dx+\int -\frac{2}{x-1} dx+\int \frac{9}{x-2} dx=\int xdx+\int 3dx-2 \int \frac{dx}{x-1}+9 \int \frac{dx}{x-2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+3x-2 \ln{|x-1|}+9 \ln{|x-2|}+ \textrm{const.}$

But [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%28x%5E3%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E2-3x%2B2%29%20%3Dx%5E2%2F2%2B3x-2%20log%28x-1%29%2B9%20log%28x-2%29): $\frac{x^2}{2} + 3 x - 2 \log(1 - x) + 9 \log(2 - x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica work in the complex plane.

Please see this article:

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1209702

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, for integrals of real functions, your answer is correct!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!